# Слово "довлеть". Почему - О?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Почему слово "довлеть" пишется через О, если - "давить"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "довлеть" происходит от старославянского "довлести" - "хватать, доставать (от быть достаточным)". И только потом оно приобрело значение "давить", "тяготить".

Comment: довлеть довле́ть "быть достаточным", укр. довлíти, ст.-слав. довьлѣти ἀρκεῖν (Супр.). См. веле́ть, во́ля; см. Преобр. 1, 71; Вайан, RES 14, 27 и сл. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

http://www.bulatokudgava.ru/speak/25_01_01.htm