# Злоба дня?

Tags: переводы

Тут недавно был вопрос о слове [довлеть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE). Судя по ответу, оно означает "быть достаточным, хватать".
Но что тогда означают библейские слова "Довлеет дневи злоба его".  Почему злоба?

Я посмотрела, вроде "злоба" = «забота», «интерес», «задача». Что-то общее конечно, есть, но не совсем. Особенно приравнивание интереса к злобе!

Comment: Кто знает переводы этой фразы на другие языки? Хотя бы на английский?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ДОВЛЕЕТ ДНЕВИ ЗЛОБА ЕГО. Книжн. Довольно для каждого дня его заботы.
Мф. 6:34. Итак, не заботьтесь о завтрашнем дне, ибо завтрашний день сам будет заботиться о своем: довольно для каждого дня своей заботы [довлеет дневи злоба его]. (Из Нагорной проповеди Иисуса). Аш.; Мих.* 
Нашла [здесь](http://www.bible-center.ru/dict/phrases/004)

*Злобу дня* я бы объяснила как "повестку дня". Само слово *злоба* - актуальность проблем каких-либо, то, что составляет интерес, потребность, необходимость, задачу (которую нужно решить), "боль" (которую необходимо устранить).

Comment: Насчет злобы пока все-таки не очень понятно.

Comment: Вот синоним вроде подходящий - наболевшее.

Comment: Да, хорошо. А не знаете этимологию этого слова (т.е. злобы)?

Comment: Надо искать в словарях. В этимологическом словаре Фасмера слова "злоба" нет, есть лишь "злободневный": "от выражения "на злобу дня". Очевидно, это библейское выражение и есть первоисточником "злобы" в значении "наболевшее".

Comment: Злоба, действительно, в основном дня. Для слова "злой" нашла в Вики:  
> Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск., ст.-слав. зълъ, зъла, зъло (др.-греч. πονηρός, κακός), русск. зло, злой, укр. злий, болг. зъл, нареч. зле, сербохорв. за̏о, зла̏, зло̏, словенск. zǝ̀l, zlà, чешск., словацк. zlý, польск. złу, в.-луж., н.-луж. złу «злой».  ... 

У этого корня много производных слов. Похоже, оно древнее библейского перевода.

Comment: Ну почему же злоба в основном дня. Основное значение - чувство злости, недоброжелательности к кому-либо: затаить злобу, питать злобу...

Comment: Я имела в виду этимологические изыскания в интернете. Конкретно - первую страницу в Гугле. Как "злоба" - так "дня". ;-))

Comment: Ага, ок :))

Answer (score 0):

Библейские слова толковать - это вообще занятие неблагодарное))).
А смысл фразы примерно таков - "Дни его полны заботами". Отголоски этого смысла слова "злоба" можно, наверное, увидеть в слове "злободневный".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это я и сама знаю, и написала в вопросе. Мне интересно, почему "злоба".  И меня интересуют не столько библейские слова, сколько их церковнославянский перевод.

Answer (score 0):

Если *добро* до сих пор употребляется в значении *имущество*, то, очевидно, *зло*, *злоба* есть ни что иное, как *нехватка*, *недостаток*. Злой человек - всего лишь невос(на)питанный, голодный, недостаточный человек.))))

"Довлеет дневи злоба его" - "Давит" (принуждает к действию) каждый день его собственная нехватка.

Хотя *довлеть*, как выяснилось, значит *хватать, быть достаточным*. Хватает всякому дню его нехватки... Да, раньше язык был выразительней (((